# cannot find -lm

Tags: compiling, gcc, sles, os390

I am trying to build gcc G4.8.5 for architecture s390x(cross compiled) on 
x86 32(sles10 patchlevel 4) 2.6.16.60-0.85.1-vmipae
for sles12sp2 and i am getting an error

```
/s390x-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
---------------------------------------------
 /s390x-suse-linux/libstdc++-v3/src'
 make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[3]: Leaving directory `toolchain_s390/build.s390x/gcc/s390x-suse-linux/libstdc++-v3'
 make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
 Error building GCC
```

Any guidance in right direction is highly appreciated

Update:
I am able to build binutils  compat  compat_binutils  compat_gcc  compat_gettext  compat_links  compat_m4  gmp  links  mpc  mpfr

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you’re trying to build the full GCC cross-compiler, but that needs a cross-built libc which you apparently don’t have yet. To build a cross-compiler, you need to

- build a stage 1 C-only cross-GCC (`configure` with `--languages=c` or `--languages=c,c++` at the most, build with `make all-gcc`, install with `make install-gcc`),
- use that to build libc for your target,
- build the full cross-GCC.

Comment: Did you build the libc too?